# Force word wrap through CSS

Tags: html, css

At the moment TEST TEST appear side by side. How can I push one down onto a second line? Only through CSS.

```
<div id="box"><p>TEST TEST</p></div>

#box{
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: well, that should automatically happen as soon as you specify the `width` of your `div` - otherwise, why should it not be in the same line ;)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't really do that. You may set the width of the element so narrow, that only one word fits into each line. But that is not a forced line break after each word.

Comment: Cheers Feeela, I was hoping to try and use 'word-wrap' somehow. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<html><head>
<style>
#box {    
    width:5px;
    display:table;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div id="box">TEST TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This changes the width of the `div`. If this is acceptable, then you won’t need all the rest, and shouldn’t use it.

Comment: Simply add e.g. `width: 3em` to the CSS rule in the question, and TEST TEST appears in two lines (ugly, but that’s what other parts of the code do).

Comment: You are right it works, I need to explore a bit more. But everywhere what I have written is being followed.

Comment: Adding to what @Amit Have mentioned: word-break: break-all;

Comment: Maybe coincidence, but this answer sure looks like it was taken directory from [CSS Tricks: Make “Pre” Text Wrap](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/); including the css comments.

Comment: For me `word-wrap: break-word;` worked

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you're trying to make the element always show one word in a line, you can use the CSS [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) property.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/DLhwJ/)

```
#box {
    word-spacing: 30000px; 
}
```

---

- P.S - You can set this property to a very large value (`32767px` on `Chrome 29.0.1` and infinite values on `FF23`) and it'll work the same way. That way it won't be coupled with the container's width.

Comment: this pushes the size of the containing box out, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants

Comment: One word below the other

Comment: @Daft Okay, Did you see my fiddle? It does exactly that

Comment: But the div is 30,000 pixels wide... I appreciate the help but thats not really what Im looking for

Comment: @Daft Nope. The div isn't 30Kpx wide, it's 100% of the screen. The whole idea of this method is that it's flexible. Look at this 200px wide example. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/DLhwJ/2/

Answer (score 11):

I use this css style:

```css
.dont-break-out {

  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px;" class="dont-break-out">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 9):

Setting the width of a element automatically breaks text inside the element

There is also an option to break a word, this can be done with

> word-wrap: break-word;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Answer (score 4):

I will do something like this.

```
<h4>lorem ipsum 
  <span class="wrap-text">
    dolor site amet
  </span>
</h4>

.wrap-text{
     white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Not sure why one of the above suggestion uses pre-wrap. I think pre-line will be a better one.
It will ignore all spaces and tabs but honour hard returns in source code.

So in your code, for places you want to wrap to the second line, do a hard return.

I like putting a span class is because with this you can make it responsive, only trigger the wrapping at certain viewport sizes. eg: @media (max-width:768px)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `width` of the div element.  The elements will then roll over to the new line automatically.

```
#box{
    width:20px; /* or a suitable width*/
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Note, however, that the height becomes dependent on the content.  If there is allot of content then the element height will also increase.

And alernative approach is to set the word spacing for the **parent** container to a high amount, eg,

```
.parent {
  word-spacing:; 
}
```

That will also force word wrap after each word.

Answer (score -5):

Simple, simply put 
    TEST<'br />TEST
only through css it is not possible unless you have two subcontainers, one for each "TEST".